# INSERT...SELECT negative double values mangled

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting some very unexpected behavior here - mysql seems to be doing math wrong in a way I can't account for. TLDR; I'm selecting a sum of a `double(7, 4)` field in a subquery, to be inserted into another table's column with the same datatype, but the insertion step messes up my math for some reason. Here's what I have:

```
mysql> create temporary table table_1 (amount double(7, 4) not null);
mysql> create temporary table table_2 (amount double(7, 4) not null);

mysql> insert into table_1 (amount) values (-500.00);
mysql> insert into table_1 (amount) values (-500.00);
mysql> insert into table_1 (amount) values (-500.00);

mysql> select sum(amount) from table_1;

+---------------+
| sum(amount)   |
+---------------+
|       -1500.00|
+---------------+

mysql> insert into table_2 select sum(amount) from table_1;
mysql> select * from table_2;

+-----------------+
| amount          |
+-----------------+
|       -999.9999 |
+-----------------+
```

What on earth is going on here? I'm using version 5.5.46-0+deb8u1.

EDIT: changing table_2.amount to a float column fixes the issue (I get -1500 for the last query)

Comment: -1500 has 4 digits before the decimal place but you specify only 3 with the scale/precision (7-4 = 3).  Why not just use more reasonable values?

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the answer [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33999). The `decimal(7, 4)` declaration truncates the given value *including digits after the decimal point*. `-999.9999` is just the maximum value that column can store.